# show Notification of Workmanager only when app is not in foreground

Tags: android, android-workmanager, foreground-service

I have a [long-running](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/how-to/long-running) worker using WorkManager library. As soon as the worker starts, a notification must be shown(?). But I don't want to show the notification when app is in **foreground**. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: I don't think thats possible out of the box.

Comment: @Darshan maybe, but I think it is a normal behavior to ask. because the purpose of having a notification is to show user that app is still working. but when app is in foreground it seems kind of pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```kotlin
val isForeground = ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().currentState.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
if (!isForeground) {
    showNotification()
}
```

The `ProcessLifecycleOwner` is the process's lifecycle, which is in started state if any activity is in foreground, and switches to stopped state (or created state, which will make the condition above false) after 700ms the app is moved to background.

The dependency exists at [this Maven link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/android.arch.lifecycle/extensions/1.1.1).

General advice: If your task may take longer than 30 seconds, you should use a foreground service, which will enforce the notification.

Comment: as I described, my work may take longer than 5 mins and it is long-running. so if I don't show notification, the work will be canceled, right? even when app is in foreground.

Comment: Showing notification while using work manager makes no difference. If you use a foreground service, it will not stop as long as you do not stop it (some devices enforce some services to stop but that's out of the scope of this answer.) Sounds like you should use foreground service directly instead of work manager, which requires a notification as I described in the answer.